# Visual Studio breaks GIF images after adding it into resources.rc

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

In my `Winforms` CLR/CLI C++ project I have the following GIF which I'm importing it into `resources.rc` as a GIF:
[image]

After I import it and save the project, `Visual Studio` modifies it to this:
[image]

Both files get modified, even the original file in my computer. Is this a bug?

**Info:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.1

Comment: Add those GIFs to a .resx file instead. The you can retrieve it with, e.g, `ResourceManager^ rm = gcnew ResourceManager("[Project Name].[The resx file name]", GetType()->Assembly); pictureBox1->Image = safe_cast<Image^>(rm->GetObject(L"[The GIF resource name]"));`. Specify `[The resx file name]` without extension: e.g., if your resource file is named `Animations.resx`, then  `ResourceManager^ rm = gcnew ResourceManager("[Project Name].Animations", GetType()->Assembly);`

Comment: Of course you can use a Folder to store the resources. E.g., add a folder to the Project, say `Graphics`, and add the `.resx` file there. Then the path to to specify will be `[...] gcnew ResourceManager("[Project Name].Graphics.Animations", GetType()->Assembly);`

Comment: @Jimi Your comment solved my problem, but the question still valid I guess, do you know why a `resource.rc` file doesn't work with GIFs plus why it causes file modification in the original file?

Comment: As soon you add a new `BITMAP` object, the first frame of the GIF is converted to a BMP image (`BM6`)